# Rmd with two equal columns

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm working with a .Rmd file, like this:

```
---
title: 'Institute'
subtitle: 'Math test'
author: 'author'
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tabularx}

---
Name: _________________________  Class:_____   date: __________

# Solve these excercises

1. $$\int{\frac{x}{x+6}}dx$$\
\hrule\
2. $$\int{\frac{1}{x^2-9}}dx$$\
\hrule\
3. $$\int{\frac{x^2+4}{x+4}}dx$$\
\hrule\
5. $$\int{x\cdot arctan(x)}dx$$\
\hrule\
6. $$\int{(x^2+1)e^x}dx$$\
\hrule\
7. $$\int{\frac{x-7}{x^2+x-6}}dx$$

<!-- Some Table with tabularx for points -->
```

Now if i Knit it to pdf, it will print a list of excercises, one below the other, and the table at the bottom of the page.

I would like to knit it using two columns,i searched online but the solutions i found would not work for me, 'cause they will arrange the excercises in two columns, filling the first one and then the second one. I would like the column to be equally filled with excercises. (best solution is to divide not by numbers of excercises but with the space they occupy in the page).

I would like to know if this can be done with few lines of code, 'cause i'm creating a web page that take as inputs the excercises i want to fill my test with, and create the .rmd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the multicol package:

````
---
title: 'Institute'
subtitle: 'Math test'
author: 'author'
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tabularx}
  - \usepackage{multicol}
---
Name: _________________________  Class:_____   date: __________

# Solve these excercises

```{=latex}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
```
1. $$\int{\frac{x}{x+6}}dx$$
\hrule
2. $$\int{\frac{1}{x^2-9}}dx$$
\hrule
3. $$\int{\frac{x^2+4}{x+4}}dx$$
\hrule
5. $$\int{x\cdot arctan(x)}dx$$
\hrule
6. $$\int{(x^2+1)e^x}dx$$
\hrule
7. $$\int{\frac{x-7}{x^2+x-6}}dx$$
```{=latex}
\end{multicols}
```

<!-- Some Table with tabularx for points -->
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i used the same idea, but i used only \begin{multicols} and it didn't work.